# How to replace HTML class when scroll with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default top-postion navbar-up" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/kotakku-icon.png"> Kotakku</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-tabs navbar-right navbar-menu" role ="tablist">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#product">Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

How to replace navbar-up class with navbar-down when scroll, and returns the class again when in scroll to the top of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this easy way with `toggleClass`:

```
$('nav').toggleClass("navbar-up navbar-down");
```

And you can put this code inside `window` scroll handler:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
     // some logic here
});
```

**Final Code:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    // you can do your own condition here
    if (scroll == 0)
    {
        $('.navbar-down').toggleClass("navbar-up navbar-down");
    }
    else
    {
        $('.navbar-up').toggleClass("navbar-up navbar-down");
    }

});
```

This way when nav has `navbar-up` class and scrolls to `navbar-up` is changed to `navbar-down` and vs when it has `navbar-down` and scrolled to top then it changes to `navbar-up`

You can see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rdutuynb/

Comment: I've added the demo version, when scrolled nav will get `navbar-down` and when returned to top: it restores `navbar-up` class

Comment: scroll == 0
0 type is what?

Comment: I check if `scrollTop()` equals 0, this will happen when you scroll down and scroll up again, this is good to restore `scroll-up` class again

Comment: Did you scroll it? It does really work, what browser are you using anyways?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll) to detect scrolling, [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass) to remove the class and [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass) to add new class:

```
$("header").scroll(function(){
  $(this).find("nav").removeClass("navbar-up").addClass("navbar-down");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use removeClass and addClass on event

```
element.removeClass( "navbarup" ).addClass( "navbar-down" );
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k5bL7pkj/)

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  $('nav').removeClass( "navbar-up" ).addClass( "navbar-down" );
});
```